# Generate Json with { character instead of [ for every json element

Tags: php, json

I am generating a Json file and the separator for every element is

> [

i would to have the

> {

character as the separator . Not sure but i am not receiving back theresult into an Ionic using Angularjs app, when i harcode the result using `{` i do receive the result. I do: $result[] = json_encode($JsonElement); :

```
$result = array();
$JsonElement = array();
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
        foreach ($row as $item) {
                $JsonElement[] = $item;
        }
        $result[] = json_encode($JsonElement);
        $JsonElement = null;
        $JsonElement = array();
}
echo json_encode($result);
```

the output

```
[
        "["123","1"]",
        "["456","2"]",
        "["789","3"]"
]
```

I would like json using this format:

```
[
        {"123","1"},
        {"456","2"},
        {"789","3"}
]
```

Comment: I don't think that would be valid JSON. The curly braces denote an object and you need to have key value pairs to indicate the name of the field and the value of the pair.

Comment: when i hardcode using { the app works how can i generate json using the { character ?

Comment: Json is `"name": value` pair.

Comment: Um... you're json_encoding stuff, and then json_encoding it again...

Comment: Have you at least readed the json documentation?? the `[` represents an array and `{` represents an object. If your code is generating it with `{` means that you have an object turning it on an `[` probably will make it an invalid json to the code that will receive it. It can work for some cases. See it here: http://json.org/

Comment: I do expect { jsonlint says it is valid json in my app using angular does not work. thank´s did not know the real meaning for {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had weird performance with JSON data from PHP to Angular. If you are using the `$http` service to send the request, you need to include in it, the headers field:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
```

And for the PHP file you need the correct headers:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json"); //Set header for outputing the JSON information
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode($result, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT); //After you're done adding in all the necessary information from the while loop
```

You shouldn't need to "hardcore"(not sure what you mean) the JSON format yourself as `json_encode` will take care of that for you. Also remove the `json_encode` from your loop, you don't need it twice:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
        foreach ($row as $item) {
                $JsonElement[] = $item;
        }
        $result[] = $JsonElement;
        $JsonElement = null;
        $JsonElement = array();
}
```

I'm a bit confused at your loop structure, perhaps I'm wrong, but I think it should be like this:

```
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
    $result[] = $row;
}
```

I think you were doing that extra stuff to get the `JSON` formatting correct?

Comment: Thank´s @Valkyrie i stop to using the foreach and it work´s. In the loop i just change to : 
`while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid)) {
           $JsonElement[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode($JsonElement, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`